# Angular app is working with specific chrome settings for language only

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular6

My Angular 6 app is working with specific chrome settings of language only

If the language is set to English US app is loaded and working, if the chrome language is changed for example to English UK app is not loading.

How to make sure my app run on whichever the language the browser settings are in OR let my app run in default English US language.

Answer (score 0):

configure the language within the index file:

```
<html lang="es">  || <html lang="en">
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```